# jQuery hover problem when moving mouse too quickly between elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, hover

I have the following html repeated many times on a page:

```
<div class="outer">
    outer
    <div class="inner">
        inner
   </div>
</div>
```

and have this jQuery:

```
$('.inner').hide();
$('.outer').hover(function(e) {
    $(this).children('.inner').show("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    }, 1000);
}, function(e) {
    $(this).children('.inner').hide("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    }, 1000);
});
```

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/342q3/15/ moving the mouse slowly between the divs (waiting for the animation to complete) achieves the desired effect of displaying only one inner div at a time.

However if you move the mouse quickly between the divs, all the inner divs remain visible.

I've tried using the stop() function but without success.  **How can I prevent the inner divs from remaining open?**

Comment: I think you will soon (adding more content into 'inner') have to completely change your script to something more 'user friendly'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you stop the animation before you start the new one (sliding out) and use `find` instead of `children` (no idea why it doesn't work with `children`), it works as supposed:

```
$('.inner').hide();
$('.outer').hover(function(e) {
    $(this).find('.inner').stop(true, true).show("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    }, 1000);
}, function(e) {
    $(this).find('.inner').stop(true, true).hide("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    }, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AVLdW/

Comment: How strange! I'd tried .stop(true, true) but with .children - I wonder why that doesn't work...

Comment: It's got to be related to children() only descending one level down the DOM; I expect the inner div is wrapped in something while it is being animated

Comment: PS: There is still a bug with this: if you mouse downwards through several divs and then stop inside one of the lower divs, the outer divs above resize as the inners animate out leaving your mouse outside the div you stopped in which still has a visible inner.

Answer (score 1):

try writing code with `animation()` that way you'll be able to `stop()` it anytime and set default styles.

Answer (score 1):

Animate() is the function you want, I have written my navigation system using this functiong with this kind of syntax:

```
$("your-selecter").hover(function() {   

    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundPosition: '0 0'
    }, 600);
    }, function() {
       $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundPosition: '0 -100px'
       }, 600); 
    });
};
```

Obviously you'd not want to change the BG position in yours, you'd call you slide function in there, but it's this kind of concept.