# Jquery animate() effect doesn't function well

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When hover on the first and second element, some element will animate to the left, it works well if hovered with a normal speed, but will crashed if hovered too fast for some times
(the text won't show or the text won't move back to its original place when mouseoff, checkout the figures below).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

1.text won't show

[image: text won't show]

2.text won't move back to its original place

[image: text won't move back to its original place][image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var flag = false;
  $(".tab-ico").hover(function() {
    var f = $(this);
    f.data('timeout', window.setTimeout(function() {
      f.find(".tab-text").stop(true, true).animate({
        left: "-=64"
      }, 300, function() {
        flag = true;
      });
    }, 300));
  }, function() {
    clearTimeout($(this).data("timeout"));
    if (flag === true) {
      $(this).find(".tab-text").stop(true, true).animate({
        left: "+=64"
      }, 300, function() {
        flag = false;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.pfm-toolbar-wrap {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 35px;
  z-index: 9990;
}

.pfm-tbar-tab-Spike {
  position: relative;
  width: 35px;
}

.pfm-toolbar-tabs {
  border-right: 5px solid #7a6e6e;
  height: 100%;
}

.p-tab div.tab-ico {
  background: #7a6e6e;
}

.tab-text {
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  height: 32px;
  left: 0px;
  line-height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #7a6e6e;
}

.tab-text a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}

.p-tab {
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 35px;
  z-index: 9;
  text-align: center;
}

.p-tab div.tab-ico:hover {
  background: #e20531;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.p-tab div.tab-ico:hover .tab-text {
  background: #e20531;
}
.tab-ico {
  width:35px;
  height:35px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pfm-toolbar-wrap">
  <div class="pfm-toolbar-tabs">
    <div class="p-tab">
      <div class="pfm-tbar-tab-Spike m_b15">
        <div class="tab-ico cart"> <i class="cbl-icon"></i>  <em class="tab-text"> <a href="">text</a></em> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pfm-tbar-tab-group m_b15">
        <div class="tab-ico "> <i class="cbl-icon"></i>
          <em class="tab-text"> <a href="http://www.qanewspdb.com/tuan/Index.aspx">text2</a></em> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where you use animate, add stop. For exemple `$(this).stop().animate(300)`. See for reference https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Here is a question with a similar problem. It is solved using the stop() method to stop the animation mlike @GermanoPlebani mentioned.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429310/jquery-hover-problem-when-moving-mouse-too-quickly-between-elements

Comment: I've added the stop() method in the snippet but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a reason, why you use complicated jquery code instead of css3 transitions?

Comment: Although there are alternatives, something that could cause problems in this setup: the `flag` variable is set in the `complete` callback of the animation. Meaning there's a 300 ms gap before it's set and in which time the `if(flag===true)` will not trigger and the timeout will not be stopped. It would be better to set the flag after the call to animate.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **css** *transition-delay property* as follows:

```
transition-delay: 1s; /* delays for 1 second */

-webkit-transition-delay: 1s; /* for Safari & Chrome */
```

Find more info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use CSS  transition, here are two links that will help you make that with less code and using CSS transition

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

https://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions